# How can I use a headset for in game chat when streaming a game from my XBox One to my Windows 10 PC?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one, streaming, windows-10

I recently upgraded my PC to Windows 10 and started using the game streaming feature.  It works great! I'd like to be able to talk to other players using a headset.

- Is it possible to talk to other players using a headset when streaming games to a Windows 10 PC?
- If so, what setups are supported?

  - XBox One Controller with a headset plugged into the controller?
  - XBox 360 Controller with a headset plugged into the controller?
  - XBox 360/XBox One Controller with a headset plugged into a USB port on the PC?
  - Something else entirely?

Comment: I stream quite frequently and have my headset plugged into my XBO controller, and then the controller plugged into the PC via USB, so I can confirm that works... not sure about anything else though, but hopefully this will help someone post a useful answer!